# Add a list as an attribute of an object

Tags: java, list, object, attributes, addition

i am currently making a meeting management application, and for each meeting there must be the time, subject, and participants. For participants, only their email addresses will be displayed. how to pass a mail list as an attribute of the object "Meeting"?

```
public class Meeting {
String room, subject;
Date mdate;
List<String> users;

public Meeting(String room, String subject) {
    this.room = room;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.mdate = new Date();
}

public Meeting(String room, String subject, Date date) {
    this.room = room;
    this.subject = subject;
    mdate = date;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? can you post some code?

Comment: @geco17 ok I edited the post

Comment: @BasilBourque sorry I misspoke

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an instance of the list.

By the way, never use either `Date` class. Those terrible classes was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

```java
record Meeting ( String room, String subject, LocalDateTime when, List<String> users ) {}
```

Example instantiation.

```
Meeting mtg = new Meeting(
    "Olympics" ,
    "Budget" ,
    LocalDateTime.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 , 15 , 30 , 0 , 0 ) ,
    List.of( "alice@example.com" , "bob@example.com" , "carol@example.com" ) 
) ;
```